# Something, presumably Gnome or Xorg uses up to 100% of one of the cores

Tags: 18.04, nvidia, 20.04, xorg, gnome-shell

From time to time, something, presumably gnome shell or xorg loads up one of the cores up to 100% making everything lag, stutter and run miserably. I'm not sure what exactly triggers this behavior, but it usually surfaces after I move the notebook around.
Restarting gnome with "sudo systemctl restart gdm" does not fix the issue. So far only restarting the pc helps, but it's a little bit frustrating having to reboot every now and then for no good reason.
The notebook is Hp pavilion 15-cs2025ur with a NVIDIA GeForce MX250 dedicated graphics adapter running Ubuntu 20.04 (Recently upgraded from 18.04, the bug's there on 18.04 as well). I'm using proprietary drivers for the graphics adapter - nvidia-driver-440.

Edit: Attaching output of htop:
[image]
Edit #2: I think the issue surfaces when I move the notebook around or shake it. Maybe when the motion sensor/accelerometer triggers orientation change (even though it's disabled in settings). Is it possible to completely or partially disable the accelerometer?

Comment: If you switch to "Processes" you should be able to see what process(es) that are using up cpu-resources.

Comment: I know, dude, at the moment the screenshot in the post was taken, gnome-shell and Xorg were at the top, hence the title and suspicion.

Comment: But no processes have high numbers in %CPU ... where the cpu usage graph at 100% when the last screenshot was taken? Eventually try to start two instances fo the monitor so both graphs and processes can be seen, or use top in a terminal instead.

Comment: It's always like that, CPU is 100% on one of the threads, but no process is shown in the processes tab consuming that much.

Comment: I'll use htop and attach a screenshot of that next time the issue occurs.

Comment: Attached a screenshot of htop as promised.